# Is there a way to ignore the errors thrown by YUI compressor because of reserved keywords?

Tags: javascript, msbuild, continuous-integration, yui, minify

I am using YUI compressor to minify my Javascript and CSS files as a part of CI process,so that we can use un-minified files for development and minify them automatically at the time of deployment. I am using MSBuild as my build engine. Now the problem I am facing is this:
**YUI throws error for javascript files that might be using reserved keywords.Is there a way to configure YUI to ignore these keywords and not throw error.** Changing the code is not an option at this time. Also I found tools like JSMin and Packer which ignore these errors,but I am not able to figure out exactly how to integrate it with MSbuild. Below is the code that I have used in my .proj file.

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Lib\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.7.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Lib\YUICompressor.NET.MSBuild.2.7.0.0\lib\NET20\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
```

```xml
<Target Name="MinifyFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JavaScriptFiles Include="SomePath/*.js"/>
      <CssFiles Include="SomePath\*.css"/>
     </ItemGroup>     
    <JavaScriptCompressorTask SourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)" OutputFile="OutputPath\%(JavaScriptFiles.RecursiveDir)\%(JavaScriptFiles.Filename).js" DeleteSourceFiles="false" CompressionType="Standard" LoggingType="Info"/>
    <CssCompressorTask SourceFiles="@(CssFiles)" OutputFile="OutputPath\%(CssFiles.RecursiveDir)\%(CssFiles.Filename)" DeleteSourceFiles="false" CompressionType="Standard" /> 
  </Target>
```

Comment: did you try adding `ContinueOnError='true'`?